# SharePoint list.asmx web service

Tags: development, office-integration, web-services

I want to build a office outlook application.
I want to display all documents with their folder and documents. I want to get all subfolder and their document file.

In Sort get all document library with their all folder subfolder and documents.

I am able to get all document library with their folders and document but can't get subfolders with their document file.

So it's possible using list.asmx web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at the [Client Object Model (CSOM).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535231.aspx) It's easier and more efficient to use in the scenario that you describe.

Comment: U mean to use jquery or javascript

Comment: If you're building an add-in to Outlook I guess you're using .NET. CSOM has API's for .NET, Silverlight and JavaScript.

Comment: Hi wictor I develop outlook application first time so i don't have much knowledge.Plz explain in brief

Comment: A quick Bing on the topic gave me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, when you call getListItems of Lists.asmx the second last attribute is an XMLNode optionQuery . u need to pass the correct xml to get fully recursive list.

xml will go something like this:

```
<QueryOptions><SomeTag FullyRecursive="True"></sometag></QueryOptions>
```

I dont remember the exact syntax as i have used it a long back try to find it out.

**EDIT**

Hey this is the exact xml i used

```
<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><Folder>" + "MobileDocs" + "</Folder><ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\" /></QueryOptions>
```

Comment: @VbPatel I have added the exact xml to my answer.